# Getting the Root-Element of an EObject which is being listened in a Tree-/Tableviewer

Tags: selection, root, eclipse-emf, viewer, eclipse-emf-ecore

What might be the best way to ask for the root-element of an Ecore-Object? I am listening to certain editors and get the `IStructuredSelection` from it. But I need to filter the `TreeViewers` further, since not all of them I am listening to contain the same elements. As far as I can see there is no direct method, which is generated by the EMF itself, that asks for the root-elements. Could you please point me in the right direction? Thanks in regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an `EObject`, you may get the desired result just by recursively checking the `eContainer()`. Such as:

```
public static EObject getRoot(EObject eo) {
    EObject parent = eo.eContainer();
    if (parent != null) {
        return getRoot(parent);
    }
    return eo;
}
```

For any `EObject` this should return the top-level `EObject` that contains it.

But instead of rolling your own like that, you may want to rely on `getRootContainer()` in the `EcoreUtil` class. Don't overlook `EcoreUtil` when working with EMF, it has helper methods at least some of which are bound to be useful in an EMF application.